# Work Done by Buoy When Displaced by Wave

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, waves, buoyancy

I have a cylindrical buoy with the flat parts on top and bottom respectively. The radius of the buoy is 3 mts. It's hit by a wave with an amplitude of 1.5 mts and a period of 7.3 sec. I want to know how much energy I can harvest with the buoy. I have read any number of papers but I can't find anything with an example, so I can't plug in values and understand what's going on, it's just the formulas and in most cases they are different or have the units wrong. How can I find out the force, work, power and energy I can get from the buoy?
Many thanks